# I tested Tango SDK Ikariotikos Version on Asus Zen Phone

Tags: google-project-tango

I tested Tango SDK Ikariotikos Version on Asus Zen Fone AR. AreaLearning After running the New Area Description in the Scene, the ADF was saved and switched back to AreaLearning Scene. However, when you run the New Area Description again, you will get the error message

"Failed to connect to Tango Service."
There is no problem with Phab2 pro. Do you know this problem? Please let me know how to fix it.

- I am using the Tango Unity3d SDK.
- The example uses AreaLearning.
- Zenfone always "Failed to connect to Tango Service."

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue. This problem occurs once you have successfully saved an area learning file, and then try to start another area learning task in the same session. If you force close the app (using the task switcher), and start the app again you will not face this issue until you have again saved an area learning file.
I worked around this problem by exporting the unity project to Android Studio, and starting area learning activities from native android. Take care to disconnect any connected tango service before starting another area learning task.